# Websocket streams check connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, binance-api-client

With the following code i open a stream connection to the Binance crypto exchange:

```
let adress = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@kline_1h';
const ws = new WebSocket(adress);
```

If i make this call for different crypto currencys then i have later a few streams open, i want to know how can i check the current open streams, is there something like a function or parameter where i can see for which currencys i have a open stream running?

because i also have the problem that it looks like streams are stopping sometimes and i dont have a good solution for checking which streams have stop and how to receonnect them. My idea is now to first find a way how to check which streams are running and then maybe if one streams is stop i will just send the connection request again.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript there is a websocket events thing, so all you need is to

```
ws.onclose = function(event) {
   ws = new WebSocket(adress);
    //just reopen it
};
```

Or, for more safety, you can

```
ws.onclose = function(event) {
    if (event.wasClean) {
        ws = new WebSocket(adress);
    } else {
        console.log('Connection error!');
        //or whatever u want
    }
};
```

**Sorry for this stupid styling, I'm newbie there**

Comment: I also new to websock technics but currently i dont find them so good. look if for example this event of close is missed then nothing which is inside the onclose function will be run. that is something which i find complicate with websockets, they send you maybe evennts which you dont get because maybe a internet connection problem did happen for some seconds. i have also try to work with readystate variable if it show me no connection then i send a new connection request but i was never satiefied with the results its overall not so good to work with websockets you have not enough controll

Answer (score 0):

If you have your `ws` variable, then checking whether the websocket is open and alive is done with

```
if(ws && ws.readyState === 1){
  // is opened
}
```

For other states of the websocket, see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/readyState).

Comment: i did try to work with readystate variable if it show me no connection then i send a new connection request but i was never satiefied with the results its overall not so good to work with websockets you have not enough control, after sending new connection request i dont know till when i will get the streams again, working with websockets looks like to complicate, working with HTTP Request to the API is much better but have to many rate limits.

Comment: there is also another big problem with this readystate variable, lets say i have 15 streams open and the readystate variable show me 1, means connection is open but i see that some streams are stopped. That is the problem i dont know for which stream it show connection is 1, do you understand this problem? So maybe the stream for btc is running but for eth is not running but you get from readystate the info stream is open, so its like useless then, or can you find exactly out for which stream the readystate is open and for which closed?

Comment: Do you have a different websocket for each connection? Or, are you trying to open several connections on one websocket? You should have one separate websocket per connection.
I am using websockets a lot and never have a problem with managing connections ...

Comment: I can not really answer that, because i dont know the diffeence maybe. I am just using the same code to send a request for a connection, the only difference is that i write other paramters, btc, eth i just change the name of the currency in the adress, what would that be a new websocket or a new connection? but good that you say there is a difference, so maybe i need to understand this difference first.

Comment: If you want to have several ws connections open at the same time, then you need one `WebSocket` object per connection. You cannot use the same `const ws` variable for several connections. Maybe you build a list of web sockets objects and manage this list.

Comment: Yes it looks like now i understand this little bit better. So my mistake is that i use the same Websocket Object for all different currency, so it would be better to create a own Websocket object for every Currency. But how would you code this if you have around 500 Crypto Currencys, do you need to create then around 500 Websocket Objects in your Code or is there some technic where you can create dynamic a new Websocket Object only if needed?

Comment: see new answer below

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive push messages from the server, you need to keep the ws connection open. If not, you can close the ws after a query and reopen it then for another query. You should wait for the closed state `ws.readyState === 3` before reopening.

If you need to keep all ws connections open, then you need a list of ws Objects. You push new objects to the list:

```
let ws_list = []  // global list of ws objects

let create_connection = function(url){
  try{
     ws_list.push(new WebSocket(url));
  } catch(err){
    console.log(err, url);
  }
}

let do_something = function(){
  for(let ws of ws_list){
    // do something with the ws object
  }
}
```